# How to check if users shared info on wall?

Tags: facebook-php-sdk

What i need to do is when user login to game and share our adv picture i want check is share successful and add extra XP points. So i created link like this:

```
<a onClick="window.open('http://www.facebook.com/sharer.php?s=100&amp;p[title]=Title of sharer;&amp;p[summary]=Descriobe abiut game etc&amp;p[url]=http://google.com&amp;&amp;p[images][0]=http://www.some.jpg','sharer','toolbar=0,status=0,width=548,height=455');" href="javascript: void;">
test </a>
```

So do i have no respond implementation. DO i need create some APP in fb and do by API with my APP ID or how to resolve this problem ?

Answer (score -1):

You can use the Facebook JavaScript SDK to track if the user successfully shared something to their wall. [This tutorial](https://www.webniraj.com/wp-admin/post.php?post=740&action=edit) shows how to achieve this.

If you share something to the wall using the FB.ui dialog box, you can add a callback to the function to track success / failure, as follows:

```
FB.ui( {
    method: 'feed',
    name: "Facebook API: Tracking Shares using the JavaScript SDK",
    link: "https://www.webniraj.com/2013/05/11/facebook-api-tracking-shares-using-the-javascript-sdk/",
    picture: "https://stackexchange.com/users/flair/557969.png",
    caption: "Tracking Facebook Shares on your website or application is a useful way of seeing how popular your articles are with your readers. In order to tracking Shares, you must used the Facebook JavaScript SDK."
}, function( response ) {
    if ( response !== null && typeof response.post_id !== 'undefined' ) {
        console.log( response );
        // ajax call to save response
      $.post( '{url_that_will_track_share}', { 'meta': response }, function( result ) {
        console.log( result );
      }, 'json' );
    }
} );
```

In this example, the callback triggers an ajax call to another page with the response from the Feed dialog. If the user shared the post, the response will contain the `post_id`. You can use the ajax script to check if the `post_id` exists and is valid and then award XP points accordingly.